# Javascript update html content with delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load more html to my page by clicking on a button and here's what I've done so far:

my main html:

```
<div class="row" id="gallery-wrapper" >
                        <div id="mixer">
                          {% for item in items %}
                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 noPadding text-center mix wdesign {{item.category_id}}">
                                  <div class="folioImg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                      <img src="static/{{item.path_1}}" alt="">
                                      <div class="folioHover2 dirHov">
                                          <a href="static/{{item.path_1}}" class="prePhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="icon-search3"></i></a>
                                          <a href="{{url_for('main.view', item_id=item.id)}}" class="detailsLink"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                <button id="load-more" class="defaultButton">نمایش بیشتر</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
<script>
    var per_page = 4;

    $('body').delegate("#load-more", "click", function(){
      per_page = per_page + 4;
      $.ajax({
        'url' : '/gallery/update',
        'async': false,
        'type': 'get',
        'dataType': "html",
        'data': {'per_page': per_page},
        'success': function(data) {
          $("#gallery-wrapper").empty().html(data);
          console.log(data);
          }
      });
    })
</script>
```

my supplementary html:

```
              <div class="row" id="gallery-wrapper">
                <div id="mixer">
                  {% for item in items %}
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 noPadding text-center mix wdesign {{item.category_id}}">
                          <div class="folioImg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                              <img src="static/{{item.path_1}}" alt="">
                              <div class="folioHover2 dirHov">
                                  <a href="static/{{item.path_1}}" class="prePhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="icon-search3"></i></a>
                                  <a href="{{url_for('main.view', item_id=item.id)}}" class="detailsLink"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                        <button id="load-more" class="defaultButton">نمایش بیشتر</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

So far I've been able to get the result I want in my ajax call, but the problem is the loaded content won't show up in my html.

And this is the response I see in my console:

```
<div class="row" id="gallery-wrapper">
                        <div id="mixer">

                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 noPadding text-center mix wdesign None">
                                  <div class="folioImg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                      <img src="static/IMG_9010.jpg" alt="">
                                      <div class="folioHover2 dirHov">
                                          <a href="static/IMG_9010.jpg" class="prePhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="icon-search3"></i></a>
                                          <a href="/view/11" class="detailsLink"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 noPadding text-center mix wdesign None">
                                  <div class="folioImg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                      <img src="static/IMG_9215.jpg" alt="">
                                      <div class="folioHover2 dirHov">
                                          <a href="static/IMG_9215.jpg" class="prePhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="icon-search3"></i></a>
                                          <a href="/view/10" class="detailsLink"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 noPadding text-center mix wdesign None">
                                  <div class="folioImg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                      <img src="static/IMG_9215.jpg" alt="">
                                      <div class="folioHover2 dirHov">
                                          <a href="static/IMG_9215.jpg" class="prePhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="icon-search3"></i></a>
                                          <a href="/view/9" class="detailsLink"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 noPadding text-center mix wdesign None">
                                  <div class="folioImg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                      <img src="static/IMG_9011.jpg" alt="">
                                      <div class="folioHover2 dirHov">
                                          <a href="static/IMG_9011.jpg" class="prePhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="icon-search3"></i></a>
                                          <a href="/view/8" class="detailsLink"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 noPadding text-center mix wdesign None">
                                  <div class="folioImg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                      <img src="static/IMG_9011.jpg" alt="">
                                      <div class="folioHover2 dirHov">
                                          <a href="static/IMG_9011.jpg" class="prePhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="icon-search3"></i></a>
                                          <a href="/view/7" class="detailsLink"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 noPadding text-center mix wdesign None">
                                  <div class="folioImg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                      <img src="static/IMG_9010.jpg" alt="">
                                      <div class="folioHover2 dirHov">
                                          <a href="static/IMG_9010.jpg" class="prePhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="icon-search3"></i></a>
                                          <a href="/view/6" class="detailsLink"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 noPadding text-center mix wdesign None">
                                  <div class="folioImg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                      <img src="static/IMG_9011.jpg" alt="">
                                      <div class="folioHover2 dirHov">
                                          <a href="static/IMG_9011.jpg" class="prePhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="icon-search3"></i></a>
                                          <a href="/view/5" class="detailsLink"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Response html is missing 2 closing Div tags therefore the syntax is incorrect and may not show up in the browser. You can check by outputting the contents of the div after it has been set to ensure in future that the content is actually being set in the DOM

```
console.log($("#gallery-wrapper").html());
```

Comment: still not working..my "data" is exactly what I want it to be. It's the html I want to replace with the "#gallery-wrapper"

Comment: See my amendment above, what is output into the console now? If it displays the html you are expecting, it's probably not showing in the browser due to a html syntax error

Comment: Yes, you're missing 2 closing divs on the response data from /gallery/update

Comment: that's just part of the response

Comment: Okay, what is displaying in the console now? after printing out the contents of #gallery-wrapper ?